# Трансформация картинок

Tags: c#, winforms, графика, bmp

на просторах ютюба встретил замечательный контент откуда узнал о возможности трансформы любой графической информации на холсте например:

```
g.TranslateTransform(x, y);
g.RotateTransform(-a);
g.TranslateTransform(-x, -y);
```

где g:

```
bmp = new Bitmap(clientWidth, clientHeight);
g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```

но если я захочу сделать рек = ректангл(а б с д) например и сказать ему - слушай парень сделай мне трансформу только с этой (рек) областью холста. Как реализовать подобное?